# How to run Unity in "headless" mode?

Tags: unity

I need to run my game without graphics and user input (headless mode).

I googled it but I actually couldn't find a solution, except something like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEditor;

public class a : MonoBehaviour {

    public static void BeforeBuild()
    {
        EditorUserBuildSettings.enableHeadlessMode = true;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me as it seems to work only on Linux.

Am I forced to run my instance on Linux?

I would be really thankful if anyone could help me!

Comment: "I need to run my game in headless mode" is it really what you need? Or you need something that is provided by the headless mode.

Comment: [This](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/688500/what-does-the-headless-build-option-do.html) may be useful to you. (Thank Google.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you'd followed the tutorial I linked you in your [other question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/128382/how-to-host-own-server-in-unet#comment223453_128382) you wouldn't have asked this one

Comment: @Leggy7 that tutorial is teaching UNET... i know how to use UNET. this question is different and i'm pretty sure that tutorial did not teach it...

Comment: From your other question: _but now I'm going to learn new unity's network service (unet). so befor start, I have question: can I host my own server in unet?_ Is this a something a taught UNET developer would say? If you follow closely that tutorial you will find out how a master is chosen among peer to act like a server.

Comment: @Leggy7 i just wanted to say that my question is different...Forget it (beside I have worked about 1.5 year with the old unity network system. so it will be easy for me to learn UNET)

Comment: Honestly, @david's question is pretty reasonable, and the question does make sense.  I'm not really sure why people get so nasty about questions like this.  Actually, a quick Googling didn't really pull up immediate results for the question.  I may have asked this here myself had I needed the feature.

Comment: @JesseWilliams check the first result from _running unity headless_. Tell me what you find. This is why people go nasty

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html):

> Unity Standalone Player command line arguments
>
> Standalone players built with Unity also understand some command line arguments:
>
> [...]
>
> **-batchmode**    Run the game in “headless” mode. The game will not display anything or accept user input. This is mostly useful for running servers for [networked games](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NetworkReferenceGuide.html).

Comment: `-batchmode` can also be useful for automated testing.